# Change colors specfic range in words

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet as shown below:

[image]

I want to change the color for characters in column E depending on the values of C and D.

The output should be like what's shown below:

[image]

```
Column C = 1
Column D = 3
```

So column E's color should change in positions 1 to 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Characters` function to change attributes of certain characters within a cell's text. The second parameter to `Characters()` is the length, not the end, however, so you just need to do a little math to get from your example to where you need to be.

For example:

```
Dim r As Range, intStart As Long, intEnd As Long

For Each r In Range("E1:E3")
    intStart = r.Offset(, -2)
    intEnd   = r.Offset(, -1)
    r.Characters(intStart, intEnd - intStart + 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is it Macro , Could you explan to me how can I write down this function?

Comment: If you want it to be. You can add this to an existing routine or make it its own macro.

Comment: @clear.choi - That question in your comment has been answered in numerous places. Do a little research and you will find the correct method. Other recommended reading would include [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @Jeeped Thank you for your advice finally I got it :) Thanks